# How to test if Pico State Machine is working?

Tags: gpio, pi-pico, ws2812

I am trying to get some WS2812b LEDs to run with my Pico. Before actually attaching them I am trying out this library: https://github.com/benevpi/pico_python_ws2812b/blob/main/ws2812b.py

It is using a state machine to drive the LEDs:

```
    self.sm = rp2.StateMachine(state_machine, ws2812, freq=8000000, sideset_base=Pin(pin))
```

When I noted that the LEDs do not change, I hooked up my 200MHz Oscilloscope and probed the GPIO pin that I set up (Pin0). The program I am running looks like this:

```
import ws2812b
import time

i = 0
di = 1
pixels = ws2812b.ws2812b(64,0,0)
while True:
    if i > 20 or i < 0:
        di = -di
    pixels.fill(i,i,i)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    i = i + di
```

The scope shows Pin0 to be low all the time. When I use the simple LED toggle program, the scope shows 490 Hz on Pin0 (as expected due to it being Python code, so a bit less than the actual 500 Hz I would like to see).

```
import machine
import utime

led_external = machine.Pin(0, machine.Pin.OUT)

while True:
    led_external.toggle()
    utime.sleep(0.001)
```

So I am thinking that something is wrong with the state machine. How can I debug that?

EDIT: I have written a minimal program inspired by the getting started with MicroPython on the Pico book. This will toggle the output with 500 Hz, ideally. However I still see no change on the GPIO0:

```
from machine import Pin
import utime
from rp2 import PIO,StateMachine,asm_pio

@asm_pio(set_init=PIO.OUT_LOW)
def half_duty():
    set(pins, 0)
    set(pins, 1)

sm = StateMachine(0, half_duty, freq=1000, sideset_base=Pin(1))
led = Pin(0,Pin.OUT)

sm.active(1)

while True:
    led.value(1)
    utime.sleep(0.001)
    led.value(0)
    utime.sleep(0.001)
```

The scope shows this image, yellow is the manual GPIO0 toggling, the blue one shows the output on GPIO1, the state machine.

[image: Scope showing output]

Answer (score 0):

Two thingsI see is that the minimum frequency for a state machine is 2000 Hz and you only define side-set pin for instruction.side(XX) not normal pins.